# Inject code without the src attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, inject, code-injection

When you inject a script like this:

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = "script.js"
document.documentElement.appendChild(e);
```

It adds this to the html file:

```
<script src="script.js">
</script>
```

But, how would I inject a script element so it would add this to the html file?:

```
<script>
//script contents
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply by setting it's HTML:

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.innerHTML = "alert('Hi')";
document.documentElement.appendChild(e);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aug78/)

Comment: @SumanBogati Probably not, but that's what the user is asking.